# Sum values ​in an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code snippet :

```
    $price = row_select('keyword_type_price', ['keyword_type_id' => $keyword['keyword_type'], 'word' => $keyword['word']], ['price'])['price'];    
        $array = [$price];
        printR($array); 
}
```

result :

Array
(
[0] => 30000
)
Array
(
[0] => 55000
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)
Array
(
[0] => 40000
)

The question is how can i merge them into a single array, to be able to sum the values ​​in the array using the array_sum function or if there is another more optimal way that i am willing to absorb.

Comment: Use `$array[] = $price` instead; with your statement `$array = [$price]`, you're initiating a new array with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize array before your loop like

$array = [];

then

change `$array = [$price];` to `$array[] = $price;`